# how to call .net dll in JMeter

Tags: java, .net, jmeter, beanshell

Can we invoke .net dll in JMeter. I have a peice of code written in .net need to use its output in jmeter as a parameter. (I am trying to call .net writen code which generate a key in jmeter.) Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

If .net dll exposes the COM interface, java can talk to that. If you can do something in java, then JMeter can do that as well.

Check [this library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) which cna access COM interface. 
Check this as well for examples: http://danadler.com/jacob/

---

But is that something which can be done only in .net? If possible, create the lib in java.

Comment: There is a  have a code to generate HAMCSHA1 written in .net 
If i can create it in java (.jar file ) how can it be imported in jmeter. 

I am using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTgwFadtPDc&t=750s the method mention in this video but i am not getting the value. 
Is there any other example you can share?

Answer (score 0):

There are following options ordered by my personal preferences perspective

1. Re-implement your .NET code in Java/Groovy using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
2. Compile your code into an executable binary and call it using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)
3. Use JSR223 Sampler mentioned in step 1 and a wrapper library like [jni4net](http://jni4net.com/), but keep in mind that you will need a .NET Runtime (Windows with installed [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) or Linux/MacOSX with installed [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/))

Comment: can I get an example for this. I have a code to generate HAMCSHA1 written in .net